# How do I show without using derivative that the slope of cosine inverse of cosines oscillate between 1 and -1?

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to show the slope of the graph of function $y=cos^{-1}(cosx)$ oscillate between -1 and 1 on contiguous intervals of $\pi$?

My textbook showed using the property that $sin(x-\pi)=-sinx$  and the fact that sin is an odd function, that $y=sin^{-1}(sinx)$ coincide with y=x and has a slope of 1on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and coincide with $y=-(x-\pi)$ and thus has a slope of -1 on $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The standard image of $\arccos(x)=\cos^{-1}(x)$ is $[0,\pi)$.

- For $0\leq x<\pi$, we know that $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))=x$, so this forms the line $y=x$ (with slope $1$).
- For $\pi\leq x<2\pi$, we know that $\cos(x)=\cos(x-2\pi)=\cos(2\pi-x)$.  Now, $2\pi-x$ is between $0$ and $\pi$, so $\arccos(\cos^{-1}(x))=2\pi-x$.  Therefore, the equation in this range is $y=2\pi-x$ (with slope $-1$).

Now, continue in this manner.